# Получение списка шаблонов, использованных для рендера страницы в Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, юнит-тесты

Я пытаюсь создать тест для Django. Моя задача проверить рендерится ли заданный шаблон при отображении страницы. Есть код

```
class OverviewPageTest(TestCase):
# Проверка передачи шаблону объекта типа player
def test_context_type(self):
    # Создаём тестового пользователя
    test_user = User.objects.create_user('user', password='password')
    test_user.save()
    # Создаём тестового игрока
    test_player = Player(account=test_user, nickname='John')
    test_player.save()
    # Получаем объект запроса к странице
    response = self.client.get('/overview', data={'player':test_player})

    # Имена шаблонов вида - "path/to/pattern.html"
    print('len(response.templates) == {}'.format(str(len(response.templates))))
    print(response.templates)
    print('response.context == {}'.format(str(response.context)))
    temp_names = [tmplt.name for tmplt in response.templates]
    print('len(temp_names) == {}'.format(str(len(temp_names))))
    print('temp_names == {}'.format(str(temp_names)))

    # Проверим, что отрендерился нужный шаблон
    self.assertIn('gamecore/main_menu/Overview.html', temp_names)

    # Проверим, что шаблону передался объект пользователя
    self.assertEqual(response.context['player'], test_player)
```

Но список `temp_names`, в котором должны лежать имена шаблонов, использованных при отображении страницы, у меня пустой. Равно как и объект `context`, в котором должен быть словарь элементов, использованных при отображении страницы.

В данном случае `temp_names` у меня должен быть такой: `['path/to/pattern.html',]`,
а response.context такой: `{'player':player,}`

(Или нет?)

Как я могу получить имена шаблонов, использованных при отображении страницы и словарь элементов, использованных при отображении страницы, используя обращение к странице с помощью self.client.get() функции?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все атрибуты объекта `response`(response.templates, response.content, response.context и тд) оказались заполненными, когда я поставил аргумент follow со значением True

```
response = self.client.get('/overview', data={'player':test_player}, follow=True)
```

Статус страницы, также сменился с 302 на 200